# NSData to display as a string

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdata

I am building an iPhone app and stuck with the following:

```
unsigned char hashedChars[32];
CC_SHA256([inputString UTF8String], [inputString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], hashedChars);
NSData *hashedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:hashedChars length:32];
NSLog(@"hashedData = %@", hashedData);
```

The log is showing like:

```
hashedData = <abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh>
```

- note hashedData is NSData, not NSString

But what I need is to convert hashedData into NSString that looks like:

```
NSString *someString = @"abcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefgh";
```

So basically the result needs to be like hashedData except I don't want the angle brackets and spaces in between.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have found the solution and I think I was being stupid.

Basically all I had to do is:

`NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", hashedData];` //forcing the `NSData` to become `NSString`

Once again thank you to all who tried to help, Much appreciated.

Comment: Hey, how did you convert the data in someString back to NSData?

Answer (score 64):

Use the NSString initWithData:encoding: method.

```
NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:hashedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

(edit to respond to your comment:)

In that case, Joshua's answer does help:

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToRemove = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"< >"];
NSString *someString = [[hashedData description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToRemove];
```

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_67

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks for your answer. I have actually tried that but it doesn't work. When I print from NSLog, it is showing a string of non-ascii characters like 'u×§v'
 
I simply need the angle brackets and spaces removed as mentioned in my original question.

Comment: stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet only removes from the ends, so the spaces will still exist in the middle. This will merely remove the angle brackets.

Comment: maybe your string is not ascii encoded? maybe you need to use UTF8 instead (pass NSUTF8StringEncoding instead of NSASCIIStringEncoding)

Answer (score 2):

Define an [NSCharacterSet](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that contains the offending characters then filter your string using -stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. My real issue is the hashedData being NSData, not NSString, so I doubt your answer is workable.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had assumed from your original post that you already had a string.